# ASP.NET: MailMessage 1.1 to MailMessage 2.0

Tags: asp.net

i'm working with an old 1.1 site that uses the depreciated MailMessage class from the System.Web.Mail namespace. i updated it to use the MailMessage class from the System.Net.Mail namespace. but, the old MailMessage `.To` property accepted a string and the new `.To` property takes a MailAddressCollection, breaking my code.

the old code looked like this:

```
_mailMessage.To = _toName & " <" & _toEmail & ">"
```

you see, the `To` property took a name and also an email wrapped in angle brackets.
how can i do this using the new MailMessage class which takes a MailAddressCollection for it's `To` property?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the MailAddress constructor inline to add recipients to your MailMessage:

```
_mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(_toEmail, _toName))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Add method.

```
_mailMessage.To.Add(_toEmail)
```

or 
    _mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(_toEmail))